# Unity Monetization.Во время Advertisement.Initialize("2282282",false); NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Пустой проект,только скачан ассет UnityMonetization,и скрипт накинут на геймобджект и назначен на кнопку.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class ggggg : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if(Advertisement.isSupported){
            Debug.Log("супорт");
            Advertisement.Initialize("3918769",true);//ругается на эту строку
            Debug.Log("инит");
        }
    }

    public void play(){
        if(Advertisement.IsReady()){
            Debug.Log("реди");
            Advertisement.Show("video");
        }
    }
}
```

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.InitializeRegistryGlobalProxy () (at <c8c8707b2adc41b09ae682df75fe1fd0>:0) 
System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.GetWebProxyData () (at <c8c8707b2adc41b09ae682df75fe1fd0>:0) 
System.Net.WebProxy.UnsafeUpdateFromRegistry () (at <c8c8707b2adc41b09ae682df75fe1fd0>:0) 
System.Net.WebProxy..ctor (System.Boolean enableAutoproxy) (at <c8c8707b2adc41b09ae682df75fe1fd0>:0)
```

Comment: Там еще к тексту ошибки дописывается `xxx was null`, что там вместо `xxx`?

Comment: [Оно?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1115722/advertisementinitialize-nullreferenceexception.html)

Comment: Удалил строки в старте,реклама не заработала(

Comment: Дополнительную информацию добавляйте прямо в пост вопроса, я помог вам перенести текст ошибки туда, а лишние комментарии удалите.